# How do I enable multiple audio outputs on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

For Windows 7, 64 bit: I have a digital SPDIF output to my stereo, which controls speakers in other rooms. I also have a set of speakers connected to the regular audio jack at the computer. This allows me to send music to the kitchen while my child plays games on the computer. Works great. Except when *I'm* playing games and still want to listen to music. ;-D

I know I can manually switch WMP to play through the speakers instead of SPDIF, but I was wondering if there's any way to enable simultaneous audio out in Windows 7? Virtual Audio Card is a non-starter because I'm running 64 bits and the VAC driver isn't signed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way built into Windows 7 to play the same audio on multiple output devices.  You can play different audio to different devices, but would need some add-on software to play to two different devices from the same application.  Applications could make it possible as well.  For example, VLC could choose to output to multiple audio devices simultaneously, but rarely do programs do so.

Comment: hrm. I suppose some irritating DRM rationale?

Comment: No.  Nothing to do with DRM.  It's just a lack of functionality.

Comment: I just scanned VLC for this feature, bud didn't find it. Please help.

Comment: Today, Voicemeeter application can output sound on 2 different audio devices. all info on www.voicemeeter.com

Answer (score 3):

Virtual Audio Cable could work, if you disable driver signature checking, as explained in the help file that is included in the ZIP:

> There are two ways to successfully
> load VAC driver under 64-bit Vista and
> 2008 Server systems:
>
> At early boot time, press F8 and
> select "Disable driver signature
> enforcement". In this mode, Windows
> will not check driver signatures
> during current session. But if you
> reboot Windows, you should press F8
> and disable signature enforcement
> again. So you need to make selection
> at every boot.
>
> Enable Windows
> test-signing mode by one-time issuing
> "bcdedit /set testsigning on" command
> from a command prompt (under
> Administrator account). This
> permanently allows Windows to load
> drivers signed by test certificates.
> After issuing bcdedit command, reboot
> Windows. 64-bit VAC driver module is
> signed by a test certificate named
> "Eugene Muzychenko (Test)" so it will
> be successfully loaded in the
> test-signing mode.

They explain for Vista and Win2008 64-bits but it's valid also for Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, but for reasons unrelated to audio, I'm extremely reluctant to run in test mode.

Comment: Just as a update, Version 4.10 (released 15.02.10) has a fully signed driver.