# How to listen to music while my speaker plays something else

Tags: windows-7, audio, music, speakers, headphones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable multiple audio outputs on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/68534/enable-multiple-audio-outputs-on-windows-7)

I want to listen to music via my headphones while the speakers play something else. I've searched the Internet but couldn't come up with anything useful so far.

How can I do this? I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (generally) isn't a Windows 7 issue, but one of hardware.  The output to your headphones is typically linked to the one going to the speakers.  The device/drivers have to support the behavior you are asking for, and most don't.

You would be best off adding a second audio interface.  You can pick up a [$2 interface for your headphones](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/virtual-5-1-surround-usb-2-0-external-sound-card-22475), and leave your good sound card for music your speakers, or vice versa.  There are higher quality interfaces out there.

Another alternative (depending on your sound card/drivers) is to use the surround sound outputs independently of each other.

Comment: Realtek HD Audio Manager gives an option "Make rear and front output devices playback different audio streams simultaneously" but I don't know how to use it

Comment: @Failed_Noob, enable that option.  Then go into the options of your audio player (Winamp, for example, allows you to do this) and pick the other sound device for playback.