# Anyway to have Audio output come through 2 headsets?

Tags: audio, skype

So I have a pretty unique sound setup for my YouTube recording... I have Virtual Audio Cable installed with 3 cables (PC Audio, Skype and an Output), I don't use the Audio Repeaters, instead I use windows' own "Listen to this device" which makes it 10x better as there is no delay in the output...

To explain what I've done:

1. PC Audio
2. Skype Audio
3. Output

I use dxtory to record my PC gameplay, I then record 3 audio streams, 1 is my microphone, 1 is (1) and the other is (2)... This is so I can remove white noise from streams (1) and (2).

Both (1) and (2) are heard through (3) which is then "listened" through my headphones via the "Listen to this device"... Sometimes I have a second person in the room doing a dual commentary, and it is too much hassle to change the cables... Is there any way, without using the Audio Repeaters (they give me a tonne of static noise and choppiness) to output to both my headsets, if it makes it easier, they are both the Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively however there is 3rd party software such as Virtual Audio Cable:http://download.cnet.com/Virtual-Audio-Cable/3000-2168_4-10067766.html

This will allow you to send your audio to 2 different outputs.

There are some other ways if you have the correct connectors:
[How do I enable multiple audio outputs on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/68534/how-do-i-enable-multiple-audio-outputs-on-windows-7)

I hope this helps.