# Is it possible to use two pairs of headphones on the same PC (cable and bluetooth)

Tags: bluetooth, desktop-computer, headphones

does any body know if it is possible to use two pairs of headphones on the same PC? One connected via cable and the second via bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively however there is 3rd party software such as Virtual Audio Cable:http://download.cnet.com/Virtual-Audio-Cable/3000-2168_4-10067766.html

This will allow you to send your audio to 2 different outputs.

There are some other ways if you have the correct connectors:
[How do I enable multiple audio outputs on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/68534/how-do-i-enable-multiple-audio-outputs-on-windows-7)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to have both connected, but sound will only play out of one at a time, It's possible to have 2 different applications play sound out of each one (e.g. Music on one, Youtube on the other) but if you want the same sound playing out of both simultaneously you would probably need 2 instances of the application open (and then try to sync them up).

Comment: On Linux using PulseAudio you can have a lot of devices (Speakers, headphones, by USB, jack or bluetooth) and device the output for each one.